# We want to replace wall heaters with radiant wall heat

Tags: hvac

We want to replace the 240v forced air wall heaters in our condo with some kind of radiant wall heat. The current units have separate thermostats and we’d like to use some kind of “smart” thermostat to control some sort of radiant wall heat. Since the current units are 240v that circuit would be ideal. The Condo is in Seattle and is pretty cool in winter as one wall is all glass. Thanks.

Comment: What's your question? Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post to be more clear.

Comment: How do you enjoy your electric bill? Some people (not necessarily in WA) get special rates for electric heat.  Others may benefit from heat pumps, which get (in Puget Sound) 4-6 watts of heat for every watt of power put into them.  And, not that *you'd* ever need this, but they also air condition. (bonus: dehumidify).

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to modern advertising, radiant heaters are not very efficient.  I grew up with them.  They take too long to heat the room, the area in front gets way too hot.

Fan heaters work better for instant heat.

For efficiency, nothing beats heat pumps.  Very roughly you spend a third in electricity cost, for the amount of heat you get.  And you can use them to cool the room in summer.